# File filtering (ASP.Net, VB.Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, filtering

I am making a filtering on files selected by user. Here is my coding that I currently use for button upload click event.

```
Dim validFileTypes As String() = {"jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "png", "PNG"}
Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
Dim isValidFile As Boolean = False

If fileUpload.HasFile Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To validFileTypes.Length - 1
        If ext = "." & validFileTypes(i) Then  'if selected url got extension like listed above
            isValidFile = True   'file is valid
            Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
            For j As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
                Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(j)
                If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("source") & "\" & Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Alert("Failed to upload! Please select file with valid extension.")
        End If
    Next
Else
    Alert("Please select image!")
End If
```

So if user select file with wrong extension, file will not be uploaded into temporary file. Since the `validFileTypes` consist of 6 types so the `Alert("Failed to upload! Please select file with valid extension.")` will appear 6 times even though the file selected is only 1. I tried to fix it but need some guidance from you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some improvements on your code and fixed some of the downsides for you.

```
Dim validExtensions As String() = {"jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "png", "PNG"}

' Check if request has no file
If Request.Files.Count = 0 Then
    Alert("Please select image!")
Else
    'Otherwise get files from request
    Dim files As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    'Loop through file names
    For Each fileName as String In files.AllKeys
        'Get file from posted files
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile = files(fileName)
        'Check content length of file
        If file.ContentLength > 0 Then
            'Get file extension of file
            Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)
            'Check if file extension is valid
            If validFileTypes.Contains(extension) Then
                'Save file
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("source") & "\" & Path.GetFileName(file.FileName))
            Else
                Alert("Failed to upload! Please select file with valid extension.")
                Exit For 'Break loop
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do appreciate it. I tried your coding and I got this error **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.** on the line `For Each file As HttpPostedFile In files`

Comment: Your coding is working great but when I select multiple images it will only check and save 1 image. If I select 2 images it will loop twice but only check 1 and same image the whole looping.

Comment: Actually, it will save all the valid files until it finds an invalid file. Then the user must choose remaining files with a valid extension and send the form again. The downside of your coding was due to validating only the first posted file, it could actually save files with invalid extensions.

Comment: I used your coding and change the line `For Each fileName as String In files.AllKeys` to this `For j As Integer = 0 To files.Count - 1`. Now the loop reading all images selected. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad that it helped. You may want to mark this as the answer? :)